# NestJS WebSocket

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs, nestjs

I use angular in the front end where I am learning to use rxjs-websockets. In backend I use nestjs, where i want to learn to use websockets. But every tutorial i see, they are explaning socket.io which i cannot use with rxjs-websocket. Using the nestjs documentation i have managed to implment till establishing connection with the angular-client(that uses rxjs-websocket) but thereafter have'nt made any progress since the documentation too talks more about socket.io than websocket.
Kindly guide me to some useful resources.

Comment: Hello @Subham. I didn't quite understand your problem. Are you not able to implement Socket in the backend or are you not able to implement rxjs-websocket? I would also like to know which version of your Angular project

Comment: Requests for links to external resources, tutorials etc., is off-topic here. It's better to post a code outline in the question of what you're trying to accomplish and people can try to guide you based on that.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, socket.io better choice due to providing the room abstractions which make encapsulation for the same events (if you will create a chat with many to many users and many rooms it's very simplify your work), and for most common cases this npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io where description covers 99% of use cases will be enough